# Proof for trivial sequence shared on facebook

Tags: sequences-and-series

I recently solved the following problem on Facebook that was shared on my timeline.

8 = 56

7 = 42

6 = 30

5 = 20

3 = ?

I got the answer **6** by using the following formula, after some inspection, 
**Answer = SQUARE(N) - N**

As I have been reading proofs recently  I wanted to know how a mathematician would prove for all integers in the sequence N > 0 that Answer = Square (N) - N?

***What I have tried:***

**Contapositive proof** but I couldn't frame -Q --> -P in English
eg **if "Square (N)  -N" is false then it is not the case N is greater than 1** was my guess but I couldn't proceed.

I have tried induction but after the trivial case of **Square(1) - 1 = 0** is true 
I could not proceed because I don't know how to frame the **N+1th value** eg 
**Square (N) - N --> square(N+ 1) - (n+ 1)**

Can anyone help or supply a method with how to prove this sequence for all positive integers?

Comment: That's an analogy why would someone prove it

Comment: As others have pointed out, to prove anything here you need more assumptions.  Maybe you know that the answer is quadratic (so $f(n)=an^2+bn+c$ for suitable constants $\{a,b,c\}$.  That would be enough.  Even knowing it was cubic would be enough (as you have four data points).  But even knowing that it is a polynomial isn't enough (you can fit  lots of polynomials of high degree through these data points, for example).

Comment: In the same vein as lulu's comment: if you only allow polynomials, $n^2-n$ is the solution of the lowest degree.

Comment: Well, I guess it is back to the drawing board with proofs!I guessed what I was doing might not be correct because all the proof methods I have studied didn't quite fit what I had in mind - still not sure how to go from reading to doing proofs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't possibly prove anything here. What if the author says "No, what I had in mind was the sequence $u_n = 7846$ except for $n=5,6,7,8$ where it has the values given above" ? How can you "prove" that your answer is the correct one ? What does it even mean ?

The formula you give indeed defines a sequence $u_n = n^2-n$ that coincides with the given values. That's all that can mathematically be said.

Comment: Furthermore, take a look at the encyclopaedia of integer sequences:
https://oeis.org/search?q=20%2C+30%2C+42%2C+56&language=english&go=Search

There are many other things that this sequence could follow.

Comment: Wow I like that ,  but how the heck do I find my sequence from the title page please?